# Does the axis of solar system precess during it's motion in the Milky way galaxy?

Tags: galaxy, solar-system

The plane of solar system makes an angle of 60° with the plane of galaxy. So, the axis of solar system should make 30° angle with the galactic plane. Like the axis of Earth precess over a long period, does the axis of solar system also precess in a similar way? If it does, do we have any estimate of the period of precession?